# Product of all prime numbers on the interval [m+1, 2m] is $\le \left(\begin{matrix} 2m \\m\end{matrix}\right)$

Tags: combinatorics

> Show that for every m the product of all prime numbers on the interval $[m+1, 2m]$ is  $ \le \left(\begin{matrix} 2m \\m\end{matrix}\right)$

I don't know how to do this, maybe somehow show that all the prime numbers on that interval are divisors of the combination number or something like that...

Comment: Consider the prime factorisation of $\binom{2m}m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Tchebychev.

> The product off all those primes appears in the numerator and not in the denominator of ${2m\choose m} =\frac{(2m)!}{m!m!}$ therefore that product divide ${2m\choose m}$.

More precisely: $\forall p, m<p\le 2m$, $p|{2m\choose m}$ therefore : $\prod_{m<p\le 2m, p prime}{p}|{2m\choose m}$. The claim follows

Answer (score 3):

> ...maybe somehow show that all the prime numbers on that interval are divisors of the combination number...

Yes, they are. How many times does such a prime appear in the numerator $(2m)!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (2m-1)\cdot 2m$? How many times does it appear in the denominator $(m!)^2=1^2\cdot 2^2\cdot 3^2\cdots (m-1)^2\cdot m^2$?