estimation of number of primes in $\{1,2,...,n\}$
I have been taking a combinatorics course in my college. I got stuck with one problem in my weekly homework. Here it is:
For any integer $n\ge 2$, let $\pi(n)$ be the number of primes in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
(a) Prove that the product of all primes $p$ satisfying $m<p\le 2m$ is at most $\binom{2m}{m}$, where $m\ge 1$ is any integer.
(b) Use (a) to prove that $\pi(n)\le \frac{Cn}{\log n}$ for some absolute constant $C$. (Hint: by induction and use the estimation on $\binom{2m}{m}$)
I have solved (a) but have no idea how use the hint to solve (b).
For (a) just consider the factorization of $\binom{2m}{m}$. It suffices to show that ${\forall}\ m<p\leq 2m$, if $p$ is a prime, we have $p\mid \binom{2m}{m}$. To do this, we only need to count the number of times that p appears in $(2m)!$ and $(m!)^2$, which are $\left[\frac{2m}{p}\right]=1$ and $2\left[\frac{m}{p}\right]=0$ respectively. So the product of all such primes $p$ divides $\binom{2m}{m}$, which means the product is at most $\binom{2m}{m}$.

How do you solve (a)? Can you use the hint of (a) and get something for (b).

For (a) just consider the factorization of $\binom{2m}{m}$. For details you can see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152199/product-of-all-prime-numbers-on-the-interval-m1-2m-is-le-left-beginmatr

I have to say that (a) is a cute problem:  $\frac{2m \cdot (2m-1) \cdots (m+1)}{m!}$ is an integer, and it is still an integer if you factor out all the primes from the top (since they don't help in cancelling the factors on bottom), and hence ${2m \choose m}$ is equal to the product of all those primes times an integer (whatever is leftover).
For part (b), I think that is more of a slog, but I can see the general idea.  Set $n = 2m$ and $C = 4$. Let $k$ be the number of primes $p$ satisfying $m < p \leq 2m$.   Then the product of such primes is greater than $m^k$, since $m$ is the smallest value for any such prime.  That means $m^k \leq {2m \choose m} \leq 2^{2m}$.  Taking the $\log_2$ of both sides, we see that $k \log_2(m) \leq 2m$, and thus we have $k \leq \frac{2m}{\log_2(m)}$.
By induction, we have $\pi(m) \leq \frac{C m}{\log_2 m}$.  Thus $$\pi(2m) = \pi(m) + k \leq \frac{(C+2)m}{\log_2(m)} \leq \frac{6m}{\log_2(m)} \leq \frac{8m}{\log_2(m) + 1} = \frac{Cn}{\log_2{n}}.$$  Some inequalities may only be true for sufficiently high values of $n$, but we can always increase $C$ to compensate.

Thank you for your help. If $m$ is odd, then $$\pi(m+1)=\pi(m)\leq \frac{Cm}{log_2{m}}\leq \frac{C(m+1)}{log_2{(m+1)}}$$If $m$ is even, then use $\pi(\frac{m}{2})$ to estimate $\pi(m)$
